# How justify this step in equipotence of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Suppose i have the sets $A,B,C,D$ such that $A\sim D$ and $C \sim A \cup B$.
How i can justify that $C \sim D \cup B$.

It's simillar to the congruences with modulo,but i don't remember how justify this "transitive" property. Thanks.

Comment: As written, this isn't true. Let $A = \{0,1\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$, $C=\{0,1,2\}$, and $D=\{1,2\}=B$. Then certainly $A\sim D$ and $C\sim A\cup B$, but $C$ is not in bijection with $D\cup B = B$. One additional hypothesis you can make to make this true is that $A, B,D$ are all pairwise disjoint.  An alternative is to use disjoint unions (which force everything to be disjoint).

Comment: @Hayden, my book says that a function must take all the elements in the domain , i disclaim with your $C$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. A function is "left-total", i.e. takes a value for everything in the domain. But I'm not sure what that has to do with anything here

Comment: You can't, since it doesn't follow. See Hayden's comment.